# Is there a way to programmatically change language of copy / paste/ select all into a different language?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change the pop up menu that gives the option paste or select all into another language after selecting another language.

Comment: Maybe start with [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/250-internationalizing-your-ios-app-getting-started)

Comment: I have already, but I am looking to change the UIPasteboard language without restarting.